# SQLite trigger execution, throws error on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-6, php-7.3

I have a table as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "matches" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "score_home" integer null, "score_away" integer null, "home" integer not null, "away" integer not null, "tournament_phase_id" integer not null, "valid_home" tinyint(1) not null default '0', "valid_away" tinyint(1) not null default '0', "kickoff" datetime null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null, foreign key("home") references "users"("id"), foreign key("away") references "users"("id"), foreign key("tournament_phase_id") references "phase_tournament"("id") on delete cascade);
```

I added through tinker the following trigger:

```
DB::statement('CREATE TRIGGER update_match_validation UPDATE OF score_home, score_away ON matches BEGIN UPDATE matches SET valid_home = false, valid_away = false; END;');
```

The statement runs without problems, I checked the database and the trigger is created. But, when updating the specified column indicated on the trigger, through tinker, laravel throws this error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: false (SQL: update "matches" set "score_home" = 3, "updated_at" = 2019-11-28 20:01:40 where "id" = 9)'
```

The curious thing is, when I update the **score_home** column, through ***sqlite*** console, the execution of the trigger is successful, doing what it should. So I believe this must be a laravel problem.

I've tried using: 0, `0`, `false`, instead of *false* but it always throws the same error.

Comment: Support for `true` and `false` as constants representing `1` and `0` respectively was added in 3.23. Are you using an older version in your php code and a newer one in the command line tool?

Comment: Also if I'm reading that error message right, there's an unquoted timestamp in an update...

Comment: I have version 3.24, if I test the trigger from the SQLite command line directly, it works without problem, I guess because the timestamps are managed by Eloquent, and that "updated_at" insertion looks weird. But then, should I report this as a laravel problem?